# Can a flight attendant have only one eye?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-attendant

I have only had one eye for many years and was a flight attendant before it happened now have received a one on one interview with airline. I just wonder if my eye will be a problem.

Comment: So you're saying you're going to be a sky pirate?  I think that's pretty awesome, would hire.

Comment: @user23206 how did the interview go? If possible please update.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2W7r_aNxrg

Answer (score 47):

Let me refer you to the answer of this other [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/can-one-become-a-scheduled-airline-pilot-with-just-one-functional-eye), that says a pilot may be considered for any class of medical (including First Class) with only one functional eye.

I think its fair to conclude that if a pilot can get a First Class medical with one functional eye, then you can be a flight attendant with one functional eye, assuming that you can fulfill all of the duties required.

Good luck.

Comment: Curious to know if there has ever been a one-eyed pilot...

Comment: @camden_kid yes, click on the question that I linked in my answer and read about a famous one-eyed pilot.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, there's no FAA requirement for flight attendants to have a medical. There is a requirement in [49 USC 44728](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44728) to hold a "[certificate of demonstrated proficiency](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/info/all_infos/media/2008/FACert.pdf)", but that's it.

I couldn't find any clear details on what the certificate requires, but it looks like each operator (airline) creates their own certification program and the FAA approves it. Based on the name, I assume that it's all about whether or not you can do the job rather than any specific medical requirements.