# Can you be a monocular airline pilot in Europe?

Tags: airline-pilot

I know this question [has been asked before](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21262/62) but it was for the US and I would like to know about Europe.

I was born with no vision in my left eye, and I have always wanted to become a commercial airline pilot, I have very good vision in my right eye. I just want to know if I could do it in Europe and if I would have any restrictions on my medical like not being able to fly internationally or fly big planes like the a380, and if it’s possible to become a captain. Or if it’s possible to get it without a soda, and would there be any differences. Or can you get a soda in Europe like the us.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! As you said, this question has been asked and answered before, so can you clarify why you're still confused and what extra information you need? I don't think we can provide a compete list of every country that allows it, but are you interested in a specific country?

Comment: It’s more like if you could do it in Europe, and if there would be restrictions on where I could fly. Because it would be annoying if I only could fly in one country in Europe, and if I couldn’t fly big planes like the a380

Comment: I'm not sure that this is specific enough and fleshed-out enough to be an answer, but: [IATA does publish a PDF of medical guidelines](https://www.iata.org/publications/Documents/medical-manual.pdf) concerning flight crew, among others. Section 3.1.2 mentions `inimal requirements to the necessary functions such as vision and hearing`. I'm not a pilot myself, so I'm not sure how open this is to interpretation.

Comment: I think that’s only about the flight attendants, it was more like if I could become a commercial airline pilot

Comment: I appreciate this is your dream but you may have to accept that being a commercial pilot is just not for you. It's not necessarily a case of "the more you want it the more it will happen" it's simply down to safety. The use of both eyes is particularly important for depth perception & peripheral vision - two very important things in aviation. With that said there are a number of flying schools catering for disabled pilots so it may be worth getting in touch with them to see if it's possible to get a private licence.

Comment: But I think that you can get a soda for monocular pilots in the us. Maybe I could move to Europe with a faa medical class 1 with a soda, and then fly in European airspace.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if you were allowed to have a medical without depth perception. IMO that is crucial to being safe in the sky and operating an aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

UK CAA [says](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Medical-standards/Pilots-(EASA)/Conditions/Visual/Visual-fields-and-binocular-vision/)

> EASA MED.B.070 (e) states that “Applicants for a Class 1 medical certificate shall be required to have normal fields of vision and normal binocular function”.

Therefore, you will unfortunately have to move out of the EU to become an airline pilot.

Comment: What if I Then get a faa class 1 and then move back to Europe. Would I so be able to fly in European airspace for a European airline. Or can’t I get a soda in Europe

Answer (score -3):

The person that speaks about two eyes being important for 'depth perception & peripheral vision' is talking rubbish. My ophthalmologist who teaches at Moorfields says one eye compensates for the lack of the second eye. CAA have understood this and wanted to change the rules but EASA stopped them. In Australia - hardly a country with a poor safety record - monocular commercial pilots are allowed to fly and have been for years. They have been sensible and understood this for years. I think in the US (but am not certain), it may be allowed too. But in Europe we are in the stone age, sadly because of nonsense like this based on pseudo science.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This does not really answer the question. Please take our tour (https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with our guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation SE. While [I agree with you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception) I sad to tell [this is not an answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) by this Q&A site. Please read the help sections.

Comment: It actually DOES answer the stated question. Yes, it does so in the middle of a rant about why the European standard is a foolish one, but that's in the realm of up/downvotes, rather than closing as NAA. AKAICT.

Comment: Hello @Forest, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. In this community we value it when people disagree with a given answer and take the time to write a better answer; which may include explaining what is wrong in the other answer. But it's considered bad form and disrespectful to say other people are "talking rubbish". Be nice to other users that spend their valuable time in making this a better site, even if you disagree with them. You can use the edit function to rephrase your answer, and I encourage you to do so. For now I will vote your answer down.