# Can I get an EASA Class 1 medical if I have monocular vision?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical

I have monocular vision (amblyopia). In the USA I can get an FAA first class medical via a SODA waiver. Can I get an EASA Class 1 Medical issued with the same monocular problem? I would be applying for a medical in Ireland.

If I absolutely can’t get an EASA Class 1 medical, then will European airlines hire ATPs with a US FAA first class medical, or do EU airlines all require EASA Class 1 Medicals?

Comment: What country would you be looking to get an ATPL from? The EU is not a country with a single rule, each EASA member state has their own implementation, so your question cannot be answered as it is.

Comment: The CAA/EASA rules for visual acuity for class 1 and class 2 are here: https://www.caa.co.uk/Aeromedical-Examiners/Medical-standards/Pilots-(EASA)/Conditions/Visual/Visual-system-guidance-material-GM/  but they are confusing enough that I would not attempt to give you an interpretation. You should talk to an aviation medical examiner in Ireland for this.

Answer (score 4):

The Irish Aviation Authority's [aeromedical site](https://www.iaa.ie/personnel-licensing/aero-medical-section) directs you to the underlying EU regulations (Part-Med), which say:

> Applicants for a Class 1 medical certificate shall be required to have
>   normal fields of vision and normal binocular  function.

That seems to rule out monocular vision completely, which is very strange (to me) considering that the FAA is very clear that binocular vision [isn't needed to fly safely](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21262/62). But medical issues are complicated, so I would definitely consult an aviation medical specialist in Ireland before making any decisions.

As for using an FAA medical certificate instead of an EASA one, that should really be a separate question. However, it's highly unlikely to be possible: generally speaking, your pilot's license/certificate and medical [have to come from the same country](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43890/62).

Answer (score 0):

I am European, and have amblyopia. Got an FAA First Class Medical without any issues. 
SODA did not apply as AME decided it wasn't necessary and signed me off. 
Have not had a reason to apply for a EASA medical, but I know pilots who have transferred without problems, and I am also aware of two pilots who have lost an eye and continue to fly with a Class 1 medical. 
Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is... maybe! It really depends on the specifics of your situation, visual acuity wise etc. I'm also in your position. I have amblyopia and will be looking to take my initial EASA class 1 in the UK around May this year. I've researched this an awful lot and have had good success with vision therapy so far - no doubt you will have heard many doctors telling you it's too late to do anything. Not so!

Comment: @J.Hougaard I removed it. The point of this site is that the information answering the question should be _here_, for other people to find in the future, not hidden in people's private mails.