# Pilots with one eye (monocular vision), versus monovision contact lenses

Tags: pilots

If it is allowed for a pilot to have one eye (monocular vision), why shouldn't it be allowed for a pilot to have monovision contact lenses? With monovision contacts one has more peripheral vision than with one eye, and overlapping vision. Depth perception is not affected that much by monovision contacts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you obtain a pilot license with impaired vision / being blind in one eye?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/can-you-obtain-a-pilot-license-with-impaired-vision-being-blind-in-one-eye)

Comment: That "dupe" doesn't even begin to address what's asked in this question; I didn't see any reference to monovision contact lenses there.  This question ***might*** already have an answer here in Av.SE, but ***that*** question most certainly isn't it.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Which country or regulations are you asking about? The rules may be different in different places.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because monovision contact lenses have a downside in that some people find it compromises the clarity of their distance vision too much, making distant objects appear slightly blurred. This would hinder your ability to see other aircraft, for example.